Python scraping code is producing an empty CSV
This website (https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/) posts new government reports. I'm trying to write python/BS code to scrape the title of each new report (i.e. "Washington Medicaid Fraud Control Unit: 2023 Inspection") and drop them all into a CSV.
I can't seem to get the python code right though. It keeps producing an empty CSV. Any suggestions?
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

# URL of the website to scrape
url = 'https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/'

# Send a GET request to the website
response = requests.get(url)

# Check if the request was successful
if response.status_code == 200:
    # Parse the HTML content of the page with BeautifulSoup
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')

    # Print the structure for debugging purposes
    print(soup.prettify())

    # Find all the report titles
    titles = []
    for title in soup.find_all('a', class_='item-title'):
        titles.append(title.get_text(strip=True))

    # If no titles are found, print a message
    if not titles:
        print("No titles found. The structure of the page might have changed.")

    # Create a DataFrame from the list of titles
    df = pd.DataFrame(titles, columns=['Report Title'])

    # Save the DataFrame to a CSV file
    df.to_csv('report_titles.csv', index=False)
    print("Report titles have been saved to report_titles.csv")
else:
    print(f"Failed to retrieve the webpage. Status code: {response.status_code}")


If you're going to write out a single array to CSV, you may want to skip the dataframe intermediary and use with open('file') and file.write() or file.writelines() - one less thing to go wrong. Have you confirmed that the converted data frame actually has data? I assume that the titles array isn't empty

You're using requests to fetch the page, which cannot process javascript.  Perhaps that is the issue.  Have you checked response.content to see if the expected items are there?

I don't see class item-title on this page.

It looks like your class selector was wrong. Try using text-no-underline hover:text-underline, which is the class used on the website:
for title in soup.find_all("a", class_="text-no-underline hover:text-underline"):
    titles.append(title.get_text(strip=True))


To get titles from the page you can use CSS selector h2 a:
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = (
    "https://oig.hhs.gov/reports-and-publications/all-reports-and-publications/?page={}"
)

for page in range(1, 4):  # <-- increase number of pages here
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url.format(page)).content, "html.parser")

    for title in soup.select("h2 a"):
        print(title.text)

Prints:
...
Ohio Generally Completed Medicaid Eligibility Actions During the Unwinding Period in Accordance With Federal and State Requirements
CMS Could Improve Its Procedures for Setting Medicare Clinical Diagnostic Laboratory Test Rates Under the Clinical Laboratory Fee Schedule for Future Public Health Emergencies
Missouri May Not Have Used All CARES Act Funds for the Older Americans Act Nutrition Services Program in Accordance With Federal and State Requirements
Fiscal Year 2018 and 2019 Biomedical Advanced Research and Development Authority Appropriations May Not Have Been Used for Their Intended Purpose in Accordance With Federal Requirements
New York Generally Identified and Corrected Duplicate Children’s Health Insurance Plan Payments Made to Managed Care Organizations
Alabama Claimed Federal Medicaid Reimbursement for Millions of Dollars in Targeted Case Management Services That Did Not Comply With Federal and State Requirements
ACF Has Enhanced Some Cybersecurity Controls Over the Unaccompanied Children Portal and Data But Improvements Are Needed
Concerns Remain About Safeguards To Protect Residents During Facility-Initiated Discharges From Nursing Homes
...

